# C#: Divide XAML-Page in different parts

Tags: c#, xaml

In Java you can create different JPanel-classes for example and put them on a frame.

I want to do sth. like this in C# too.

I have a XAML-Page with two equal parts. I want to put the part in a different "element" and include them tow times in the xaml-page.

Its possible to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can create the usercontrol in XAML and that user control you can place in your pagecontainer on your page.

Plaese visit this. might it can help you.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/UserControl.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You must in fact put the different controls of your application in different userControls (Add New =>Silverlight UserControl in Visual Studio)

an classic UserControl XAML File looks like that:

```
<UserControl xmlns="..." xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:class="MyApp.MyControl" >
  [...]
</UserControl>
```

VS will generate the MyApp.MyControl class for you.

Then, in another UserControl, you can use the MyControl UserControl:

```
<UserControl xmlns="..." xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp" x:class="MyApp.MyMainControl" >
  [...]
  <local:MyControl />
  [...]
</UserControl>
```

here the local xml namespace points to the MyApp .NET namespace in the same assembly. In fact, any control used in a xaml file (for instance an user control) is simply a class.